# Сделать перебор списка элементов и увелчить его значение относительно предведущего

Tags: javascript

Что хочу  сделать. Выстроить квадраты в ряд с помощью js. Чтоб вручную не выставлять позицию каждого. Столкнулся с тем что я никак не могу это сделать. Помогите пожалуйста. Вот код:

https://jsfiddle.net/Ln6tLxq2/

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('li');
console.log(elements);
for (var n = 0; elements.length >= 4; n++) {
  elements[n].style.left = 50 + 'px';
}
```

```css
li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class=item style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px;"></li>
  <li class=item style="position: absolute; left:50px; top: 50px;"></li>
  <li class=item style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px;"></li>
  <li class=item style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px;"></li>
  <li class=item style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px;"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: цикл странный, на самом деле: какой смысл проверять количество элементов в коллекции, если внутри цикла коллекция никак не изменяется?

Comment: добавь картинку, что в итоге должно получиться, что значит _Выстроить квадраты в ряд_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что у вас с проверкой в цикле? Проверяете `elements.length >= 4`? Но смысл?

Ваша задача пройтись по элементам и задать каждому значение относительно его расположения.

Так?

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for (var n = 0; n < elements.length; n++) {
  elements[n].style.left = n * 50 + 'px';
}
```

```css
li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class=item style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px;"></li>
  <li class=item style="position: absolute; left:50px; top: 50px;"></li>
  <li class=item style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px;"></li>
  <li class=item style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px;"></li>
  <li class=item style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px;"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Да, так, спасибо.